# How to intercept multipart/form data in fiddler and access a binary file which is a part of the request

Tags: fiddler

I am trying to intercept requests send to a server from my mobile device. There is this post request which will upload payload to the server and the request has a file of type .pb, which i cant read in fiddler. Is there a way to get hold of the file ?

Comment: Are you really using Google's `protocol-buffers` library? If not, please remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It's not clear what "i cant read in fiddler" means.*

Use Fiddler's **HexView** request inspector to inspect the POST body. You can select the bytes of the file upload and choose **Save bytes** to save the file out to your desktop.